# php regex replace within results

Tags: php, regex

I want to run over a css file and replace some values.
I want the replace to take place only within the Braces.

**for example** lets say we have the next css:

`.redColor{color:red;padding-right:45px;/*etc....*/}`

and I want to replace all the red values with blue.

I had tried to use the next code :

`preg_replace("/{(.*)red(.*)}/","blue",$cssString)`

but the result where:
`.redcolorblue` I want it to replace just the red only if it's withing braces and avoid the pattern around it...
the expected result should be:

`.redColor{color:blue ;padding-right:45px;/*etc....*/}`

This just an example for what I am trying to do, I want to change the css file itself, and change a lot of values inside it.

**some clarifications**
I want to do this replace in a CSS file, so I am loading the whole file into a variable and doing the replace, so solutions that replace only one value are not what I amlooking for

Comment: yes I do, this is just an example.. :-)

Comment: You might find it easier to use Regex to extract the 'chunks' (blocks within braces), do replacement on that chunk and then replace the old one with the new one.

Comment: You might want to consider a PHP CSS parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(\{.*?)red(.*?\})/s', '$1blue$2', $cssString);
```

Comment: thanks but this is not working, it removed the braces as well

Comment: by the way, what is the meaning of "/s" ??

Comment: `/s` makes the dot `.` match newlines

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/({.*)red(.*})/","${1}blue${2}",$cssString);
```

By using parentheses matching string is saved and can be referenced in replacement string as `$1`.

More details in http://php.net/preg_replace